C# xunit tests - How can i get output from exe file in tests
In my xunit test im using a powershell SDK to run my powershell function and that function should run an exe file then parse the output and return it.
This is the powershell function:
function Get-D2Metadata() {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string]$InstallDir
    )
    
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $InstallDir)) {
        Write-Error "The path '$($InstallDir)' does not exist."
        return
    }

    $d2StartPath = ""

    $binPaths = @("$($InstallDir)\bin", "$($InstallDir)\bin64")
    $exeNames = @("d2start.exe", "startcli.exe")

    foreach ($binPath in $binPaths) {
        foreach ($exeName in $exeNames) {
            $tempAppPath = Join-Path -Path $binPath -ChildPath $exeName
            if (Test-Path -Path $tempAppPath) {
                $d2StartPath = $tempAppPath
                break
            }
        }
        if ($d2StartPath) {
            break
        }
    }

    if ($d2StartPath -eq "") {
        throw "Valid exe was not found."
    }

    # $output = Invoke-Expression "& $($d2StartPath) -help"

    $tempDirPath = "C:\temp\$(New-Guid)"
    New-Item -Path $tempDirPath -ItemType Directory -Force > $null

    try {
        Start-Process -FilePath $d2StartPath -ArgumentList "-help" -NoNewWindow -RedirectStandardOutput "${tempDirPath}\output.txt" -Wait
        $output = Get-Content -Path "${tempDirPath}\output.txt"
    }
    finally {
        Remove-Item $tempDirPath -Recurse -Force
    }

    $product = $output[3].Split(' ')[1]
    $release = $output[3].Split(' ')[4].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "")
    $version = $output[3].Split(' ')[2]

    $D2Metadata = @{
        "product" = $product
        "release" = $release
        "version" = $version
    }

    return $D2Metadata
}


And this is part of the test where it fails:
[Fact]
public async Task TestGetMetadata()
{
    using var powershell = await new PowerShellWrapper().CreatePowerShellAsync();

    powershell.AddStatement()
        .AddCommand("Get-D2Metadata")
        .AddParameter("InstallDir", @"C:\D2000\D2000_V23.0.78_server\D2000_EXE");

    var result = await powershell.InvokeAsync();
    var baseObject = (Hashtable)result[^1].BaseObject;

    baseObject["product"].Should().Be("BASIC");
    baseObject["release"].Should().Be("A240305078-02");
    baseObject["version"].Should().Be("V23.00.078");
}

My problem is that in test the exe file is not returning any output (it fails in the powershell function at the Start-Process, file where should the output be is empty). However when i tried it in normal console app it worked fine, even when its the same code.
I checked if test environment had access to the exe file. All the paths and parameters should be correct too. I tried to use MSTest framework too, but got the same result of exe file returning null. I got the same issue when i tried to start process just in c# without the powershell and get the output from there, but it returned null too. There is probably some problem how tests run, but idk what i should look for.

Might be worth checking the bitness of the executing PowerShell session (and writing the bitness to the console at the start of the script). Your tests might not be running using the bitness you expect, which could potentially affect your code. You can use commands like $is64BitPowerShell = ([Environment]::Is64BitProcess) and if ([System.IntPtr]::Size -eq 8) for this.

I just checked and everything is 64bit, PowerShell session, C# tests and exe file too.

What do you mean by 'it is always null'? What is always null? When you say "it fails ... at the Start-Process", what happens? What error is displayed? It would be useful to write the contents of all the variables you're using on the problematic line to the console output immediately beforehand (and post those here too).

No error displayed, with -RedirectStandardOutput "${tempDirPath}\output.txt" i redirect the output to a file and when i check the file, its empty. And all variables are just paths to exe and output file which are correct.
